# What is the reversal of a regular language useful for?

Tags: regular-languages

There is a number of questions on this website about the reversal of regular languages:

- [Closure under reversal of regular languages: Proof using Automata](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54934/closure-under-reversal-of-regular-languages-proof-using-automata)
- [Proving that the reversal of a language reversal is that language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52037/proving-that-the-reversal-of-a-language-reversal-is-that-language)
- etc.

I was wondering what was this concept useful for.
Does the fact that the reversal of a regular language is regular has some interesting corollaries for example? Does considering the reversal of a language helps in certain proofs?